# How to trace steps in SQL profiler for only particular application

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, profiler

We are using a third party company's software that talks to a SQL Server database and retrieves and inserts all the information.

When a user uses this software sometimes it freezes at a particular step. 
I need to troubleshoot it and find out why it happens.

Basically I want to use this UI software and at the same time see what query runs at each step I am performing.

For that I am using SQL Profiler to see what query causes this bottleneck. 
But how would I trace steps only for that particular software and only for a particular user? I don't want to see all other information.

[image]

I am able to filter NTUserName, which I am assuming is just UserName, correct?

But how can I find out what is the ApplicationName?

If I ran this query I see 13 different applications, including Microsoft Office, Report Server etc. None of them sounds like the name of the software we use. (MGA Systems. Insurance Management System)

```
select distinct 
    program_name
from sys.dm_exec_sessions
where is_user_process = 1;
```

Comment: The ApplicationName will be the value specified in the connection string, or if none is specified, a default value that varies depending on the client API. For example, SqlClient will use the generic ".Net SqlClient Data Provider'" value when Application Name is not specified.

Comment: If the application is not playing nice and providing a specific name, then get the hostname of the workstation it is connecting from and filter on that.

Comment: Thank you guys, hostname helped a lot.  And yes, the application name  is ".Net SqlClient Data Provider'".
Thanks again

Comment: @DanGuzman You should post the information as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ApplicationName will be the value specified in the connection string, or if none is specified, a default value that varies depending on the client API. For example, SqlClient will use the generic ".Net SqlClient Data Provider'" value when Application Name is not specified.